# Projecting WMS layers from GCS_WGS_1984 to UTM ED50 31N using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wms, coordinate-system

I'm using a WMS service to open different layers. Specifically I'm using this link:

http://w24.bcn.cat/WMSBaseGuia/request.aspx

I have the following problem. When I open these layers with Arcmap, its projection is:

```
Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984
Datum:  D_WGS_1984
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

However I would like to transform it (or project) to Europe UTM ED50 31N (units meters).

Anyone can help me to obtain this projection with ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a layer to Arcmap, If this is the first layer, Arcmap will automatically set the coordinate system of data frame to that of the layer.

When you add a second layer in a different coordinate system, Arcmap tries to project that layer (here WMS), to the projection system of the data frame (If there is a valid transformation between them).

Now, Here you should set the coordinate system of your data frame to : **"Europe UTM ED50 31N"**

Then add your WMS Layer. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Start a new, blank map or in your current map go to step 2.
2. Double-click or right-click > properties on the dataframe (named
   Layers by default) in the Table of Contents (ToC).
3. Go to the Coordinate System Tab, drill down through folder tree to
   Projected Coordinate Systems > UTM > Europe > European Datum 1950
   UTM Zone 31N and highlight it, then click Ok.

Your dataframe is now set to that coordinate system and any data you add will be reprojected on-the-fly to it when you add it. If data layers are already present, they will be reprojected to the CRS you set. If the data doesn't share the same datum you will get a warning box about selecting a Transformation, either when you go to add the first layer on a different datum or when you try to apply a projection to the dataframe that already has layers of a different datum in it.

In your case, since your layers are in WGS84 and you want the ED50 datum, you'll need to click the Transformation button on the warning box. If you click the bottom dropdown box, you'll get a list of potential transformations to select from in the order that ArcGIS thinks is most appropriate based on your data. The difference between transformations is that they can be optimized for certain areas of the world. You don't mention what area you're specifically looking at. There is a [PDF file](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/003r/pdf/geographic_transformations.pdf) linked in the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003r00000010000000) that may assist in choosing the right one. For example if you're looking at France, ED_1950_To_WGS_1984_17 might be the best to use, whereas for Denmark ED_1950_To_WGS_1984_25 might be better. Note that one transformation works both directions, to the two sides of the 'to' phrase are interchangeable.

Be aware that you cannot permanently reproject the data because you're just viewing it through a service, not altering it, and there may be a performance hit when reprojecting a service layer on-the-fly. Also note there was a bug in 10.1 where when adding base layers it would automatically reset the dataframe projection. Not sure if that would affect other things like WMS layers. You can go back to the coordinate system tab of the dataframe (not the individual layers) at any time to verify it is still correct or change it to something else.